# What is the minimum buffer size for sprintf with %g?

Tags: c, double, printf

The problem is to statically allocate a buffer large enough to fit a printed double, formatted with %g at maximum precision.  This seems like a simple enough task, bu I'm having trouble.  The best I have come up with (assuming the number to be printed is x) is

```
char buf[1 + DBL_DIG + DBL_DIG + 1 + 1 + 1 + DBL_DIG + 1];
int len = sprintf(buf, "%.*g", DBL_DIG, x);
```

The DBL_DIG macro is from float.h, and apparently it is supposed to indicate the maximum precision for the type double.  We need:

- 1 byte for a negative sign
- enough bytes to capture the significant digits
- at most one 'separator' char (comma, etc.) per digit
- 1 byte for a decimal point
- 1 byte for 'e'
- 1 byte for the sign on the exponent
- some bytes for the exponent
- 1 byte for the trailing null written by sprintf.

I'm using the number of significant digits as an upper bound on the number of digits in the exponent.  Have I made any errors?  Is there a better solution?  Should I just allocate 64, 128, or 256 bytes and hope for the best?

Comment: Is there a reason that you can only use such a precise amount of memory?

Comment: I'm not sure the answer, but one thing I want to advise against is using sprintf. You should always use snprintf so that if your calculation of minimum buffer size is wrong, you won't overflow the buffer: "snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), ...);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `sprintf`, you could use [`asprintf`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=asprintf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.2-RELEASE&format=html). This allocates a buffer of the correct size to fit your string.

Comment: I don't understand why people like snprintf so much.  If you are going to use a non-portable function, why not use one like asprintf which gets the job done directly?

Answer (score 5):

Use `snprintf()` to find out how many characters you need:

```
#include <float.h> /* DBL_DIG */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  double x = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
  char find_len[1];
  int need_len;
  char *buf;

  need_len = snprintf(find_len, 1, "%.*g", DBL_DIG, x);
  buf = malloc(need_len + 1);
  if (buf) {
    int used = sprintf(buf, "%.*g", DBL_DIG, x);
    printf("need: %d; buf:[%s]; used:%d\n", need_len, buf, used);
    free(buf);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

<s>You need a C99 compiler for `snprintf()`.</s>
`snprintf()` was defined by the C99 standard. A C89 implementation is not required to have `snprintf()` defined, and if it has as an extension, it is not required to "work" as described by the C99 Standard.

Comment: Are you sure that you need a C99 compiler for snprintf?

Comment: Consider `#include <stdio.h>` added to `int main(void) { double snprintf = 42; return snprintf - 42; }`. That makes a strictly conforming C89 program, and a required diagnostic for C99. Of course C89 compilers are allowed to provide extensions.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot pre-calculate the size at compile time. The %g formatter takes the locale into account (for the 1000's separator etc.)
See http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf for a description on how to calculate the size safely.

Comment: Brilliant!  I forgot about the locale.  Adding an extra DBL_DIG / 3 should cover that, right?

Comment: Not really. For example in India they count in "lakhs" and "crores" with separators for 100 thousand (lakh) and 100*100 thousands = 10 million (crore) etc.

Comment: Good stuff.  So we make the term to cover digit separators a full DBL_DIG.  No one could possibly use more than one separator per digit, could they?  Are there any other locale-specific variations?

Comment: jkl, I'm not a locale expert, but I learnt that once locales come into play, forget all your assumptions. I'd voe for `snprintf`, too

Comment: Assuming I don't want separator characters or other locale-specific features in the output, I just temporarily set the locale to 'C' and then set it back when the printing is done.  Does that make estimating the buffer size easier?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:  %g does not show all of the representable digits, %g shows a nice-for-humans rounded result.  You can specify the precision using %f or %e if you would like a different result.

Never use sprintf() rather than using snprintf().  In your case:
`int len = snprintf(buf, dimensionof(buf), "%.*f", DBL_DIG, x);`

Answer (score -2):

> Should I just round up to 64, 128, or
>   256 and hope for the best?

Yes, just do that -.-